# Estimating random effects model with unequal spacing by respondents

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model

Can you estimate a random effects model when you have unequal spacing by respondents? For example, in the [NLSY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Longitudinal_Surveys) you can get health data in 1992, 1994, and when the respondent turns 40 which is between 1998-2006. So you can technically estimate a Random Effects model where the spacing can vary across respondents depending on when they took the 40 year old health module. One person's time points may be 92, 94, and 98, while another person's time points may be 92, 94, and 2006.

The sample will be unbalanced from 1998-2006 since it will only contain 1/5 of respondents on average. Also this model will have 7 time periods (92, 94, 98, 00, 02, 04, 06) but the maximum time periods for any one respondent will be 3, is that okay? The problem I'm most worried about is the unequal spacing by respondents. One person may have a 4 year gap, while another may have a 12 year gap. Can you estimate this model, or will it be too biased?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just treat time as a random slope. The unequal spacing is not a problem. (Sorry no time for a full answer)